# После установки defaultMode в mui, все установленные вручную стили были сброшены, как их вернуть?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui

Я использую в одном проекте как компоненты из mui/material, так и из mui/joy.
Попыталась установить Темную тему, именно для компонент из mui/joy (установка темы в mui/joy немного отличается от установки темы в mui/material):

```
import { CssVarsProvider, extendTheme } from '@mui/joy/styles';

const theme = extendTheme({ cssVarPrefix: 'demo' });

    <CssVarsProvider
      defaultMode="dark"
      theme={theme}
      colorSchemeSelector="#demo_dark-mode-by-default"
      modeStorageKey="demo_dark-mode-by-default"
      disableNestedContext
    >
...Components

</CssVarsProvider>
```

Проблема: после запуска кода у всех компонент, вложенных в `<CssVarsProvider>`, отменились заданные с помощью mui стили (цвета, шрифты, границы, ховеры и тд).
И после удаления `<CssVarsProvider>` все заданные вручную стили не срабатывают при отрисовке.

Удаление всех пакетов mui из package.json не решило проблему, будто бы эта настройка записалась куда-то глобально.

Хотелось бы вернуть все обратно, как-нибудь отменить эту настройку.

Буду благодарна за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Всё исправилось после установки `disableNestedContext={false}`.
Всем спасибо, всем крепкого здоровья! Жизнь прекрасна!